# Stitching thousands of .png files with Fiji

Tags: fiji

I wrote a Node.js app that creates images that I want to stitch. I want to create one image with over 10,000 charts. My original solution was to create images each with over 200 charts each and stitch those together. That results in 50 images being stitched.

I now wish to create one chart per image, resulting in over 10,000 images, and stitch those together. When I drag and drop the files into Fiji to create a montage, it opens each individual one. It takes way to long to open the entire collection.

Is there a way I can create a montage of thousands of images and stitch everything into a single file in Fiji that doesn't require every image being opened?

Answer (score 0):

You say that you want to stitch your image, which implies your goal is to find where these images overlay from a specific channel, but when you say montage, it makes it seem like what you really want to do is concatenate the images into a stack or align them into a montage.  To me it appears that you have a program which will output some form of stack which has 200 planes, and then concatenate them together or align them as a montage.

In principle, you will have to open every image, but opening them with batch mode on and running the operations by macro will reduce time by not rendering the viewable image.  It would not be possible to run ImageJ/FIJI operations on an image without opening it, as this is beyond something like renaming or deleting a file.

If you really meant that you want to stitch them, use the stitching plugin function for Grid/Collection stitching, and set the overlap to zero.  This requires having your images be in a single folder, and in your case splitting them into individual images instead of sets of 200, with each file labeled with an increasing number (i.e. file_name_1.tif, file_name_2.tif, where each file_name is the same and only the number changes).  If you have stacks of 200 and are happy to keep them that way in the created montage, the file naming convention needs to be the same.  You should select the Fuse and Display option to get the resulting image.  The output will be a merged, larger image.

When you are trying to somehow stitch the images and overlay the stacks, scripting the commands to run it in batch mode would also work.

Answer (score 0):

For stitching I highly recommend the MIST plugin. For batch opening files, try dragging and dropping the folder containing the images rather than the images themselves. Alternatively, go through File -> Import -> Image Sequence.